# LINQ to SQL with a large database table increase performance

Tags: c#, linq

I am doing a search on a database table using a wildcard(The `contains` extension) Here is the code

```
// This gets a list of the primary key IDs in a table that has 5000+ plus records in it
List<int> ids = context.Where(m => m.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())).Select(m => m.Id).ToList();


// Loop through all the ids and get the ones that match in a different table (So basically the FKs..)
foreach (int idin nameId)
{
    total.AddRange(context2.Where(x => x.NameID == id).Select(m => m.Id).ToList());
}
```

In there anything I could change in the LINQ that would result in getting the IDs faster?

Thanks

Comment: In the item class of `context2`, is there a reference to the `Name`, the item class of `context1`? In other words, is `x.Name.name` possible in the predicate?

Comment: No, `Context2` has the FKS of the PKs of `Context1`, would it be faster  to use a virtual type in COntext2? so `Context.name.where..`

Comment: I don't think it would be faster, but more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested it, but you could do something along these lines:

```
var total =
    from obj2 in context2
    join obj1 in context1 on obj2.NameID equals obj1.Id
    where obj1.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower())
    select obj2.Id
```

It joins the two tables, performing a cartesian product first and then limiting it to the pairs where the `NameId`s match (see [this tutorial on the `join` clause](http://www.dotnetperls.com/join)). The `where` line does the actual filtering.

It should be faster because the whole matching is done in the database, and only the correct ids are returned.

If you had a `Name` property in the `context2` item class that holds a reference to the `context1` item, you could write it more readable:

```
var total = context2
    .Where(x => x.Name.name.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.toLower()))
    .Select(x => x.ID);
```

In this case, Linq to SQL would do the `join` automatically for you.

Comment: Of course, I was doing 2 queries where as I could have used a join as you rightly pointed out. Need to get use to the style of LINQ you posted. I guess its more SQL like. thanks!

Comment: In fact, you were doing one query for each name that matches the search string, so for short search terms that's a lot of queries.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance you can see tests that show if you search 1 string in 1 000 000 entries its around 100 ms.

Here is the [link](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-check-if-a-string-occurs-within-a-string) with tests and implementation.

```
for (int y = 0; y < sf.Length; y++)
    {
        c[y] += ss.Where(o => o.Contains(sf[y])).Count();
    }
```